# Add childTabView in TabView

Tags: android, eclipse, tabview

Good Evening, i have some question for my project. This is the case :

- I have 3 tabview in my app

[This the third tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttuOz.png)

- i want add a child tab below the cardview with 2 child tab.

I try looking some question with the same case with me but i dont have any idea to add new this child tabview

This is my tab_3.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_btn" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/CardView1"
        style="@style/CardView.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/our_team" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_image" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btCall"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
                android:text="Call"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btMessage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
                android:text="Message"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="KINANDAYU"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I'm using Eclipse. I want to add childtabview in tab_3.xml but I don't know exactly the code. Every answer is useful for me. Thanks in advance